# Nav Bar not appearing on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I ran into this issue where the nav bar would not appear in mobile mode!

here is my code!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>LotusNetwork &heartsuit; Home</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> !-->
<!-- Stylesheet does not work !-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="LotusNetwork is a expanding Minecraft server with a blossoming community">
<meta name="keywords" content="HCF Server, Minecraft, lotuspvp.us, Adios, LotusNetwork, LotusHCF, LotusPvP, HCF">
<meta name="author" content="Lotus Network">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                <style>
                /* Background Image */
                    body  {
                        background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
                    }

                    /* Lotus Logo Align */
                    html,
                    body,
                    #wrapper {
                        height: 100%;
                        width: 100%;
                        border: 0;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }
                    #wrapper td {
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    /* Navagation Bar */
                    .navbar-collapse {
                        text-align: right;
                    }

                    .navbar-nav {
                        display: flex;
                        float: none;
                        margin-top: -70px;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        list-style-type: none;
                        width: 1450px;
                        position: fixed;
                    }

                    .navbar .nav > li > #test {
                        display: block!important;
                        background: url(img/lotuslogo.png) no-repeat;
                        width: 183px;
                        height: 64px;
                        text-indent: -99999px;

                    }

                    .navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0;
                        box-shadow: 0 0;
                        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
                        background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 100%;
                        border-width: 0;
                        position: fixed;
                    }

                    .fntcolor {
                        color: #FFF;
                    }
                </style>

<head>

    <body>
        <table id="wrapper">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="img/lotuslogo.png" alt="logo"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
                                      <div class="nav">
                                        <!-- Nav Bar !-->
                                        <div id="navi">
                                            <nav class="navbar-inner">
                                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="pageWidth">
                                                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  </button>
                                                                </div>

                                                                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
                                                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                                                                        <li class="navhome">
                                                                            <a class="home" href="index.html" class="fntcolor">Home</a>
                                                                        </li>





                                                                        <li class="navdonate">
                                                                            <a class="donate" href="http://lotuspvpmc.buycraft.net" class="fntcolor">Donate</a>

                                                                        </li>





                                                                        <li class="navreddit">
                                                                            <a class="reddit" href="http://reddit.com/r/LotusNetwork/" class="fntcolor">Forums</a>
                                                                        </li>

                                                                        <li class="navstaff">

                                                                            <a class="staff" href="staff.html" class="fntcolor">Staff</a>
                                                                        </li>

                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <a href="#" id="test"></a>
                                                                        </li>
                                        <div class="staffimg"> <img src="img/staff.png" alt="logo2" width="64" height="64"> <style> div.staffimg { top: 600px;  right: 205px; position: fixed; } </style> </div>

                                        <div class="forumsimg"> <img src="img/forums.png" alt="lol" width="64" height="64"> <style> div.forumsimg { top: 600px;  right: 463px;  position: fixed; } </style> </div>

                                        <div class="homeimg"> <img src="img/lotushome.png" alt="home" width="64" height="64"> <style> div.homeimg { top: 608px;  right: 991px;  position: fixed; } </style> </div>

                                        <div class="donateimg"> <img src="img/donate.png" alt="home" width="64" height="64"> <style> div.donateimg { top: 600px;  right: 732px;  position: fixed; } </style> </div>


                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem? Could it be `position: fixed;` not sure what it is but I do need that position fixed as it is the part

Comment: Get a navbar from here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: That is the default behaviour of bootstrap... It hides the navbar as it has less space in mobile screen but still you can open your navbar by clicking on the collapsed icon that appears in mobile view...

Comment: So did my answer work for you?

Comment: Nope as it bugs out I want the nav bar spaced out and transparent I am fine with the white on mobile but concerned on the glitch.

Comment: ok sorry :( my bad

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the way that the collapsible navbar in Bootstrap is intended to work.

Your nav is contained in this element:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
```

If you look at the code here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/less/navbar.less#L40-L73

The `.collapse` class hides the element (by adding a `display: none`), but when the screen size is larger than the breakpoint (768px which is @grid-float-breakpoint)  this code overrides that with a `display: block!important` to show the element.

Comment: The !important is the keypart as it displays the images on my nav bar! any ideas on what i can do?

Comment: Well, I guess that if you simply want it to display on mobile too, you can simply take the collapse class off the div.

Answer (score 0):

There is many possibilities why your navbar not appearing in mobile.

**1**. I see the line of code where you set `<nav class="navbar-inner">` and your navbar toggle already at there but the background is transparent., 
actually it should be like this you need to add `<nav class="navbar-default navbar-inner">`.

Here is [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/DaGy8Mm81R)

i already add your code in that demo. It run perfectly.

**2**. Check your bootstrap css and js also jquery link if it running properly.

Comment: uhm so what happens when i do that is it on;y displays the home and that is 1/3 of it and none of the other.

Comment: you need to fix your css first bro.

Comment: that why i say your CSS is the main problem right now. I already showing your navbar appearing in mobile